# How to efficiently configure Firebase notification for my Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, console, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to receive Notifications with the Firebase Console.
**My main goal is to send a notification message to all devices that have my App installed**, even if the app is not running at all (killed).

I've learned that there are two big situation to afford:

1. the app is in foreground/background mode.
2. the app has been killed.

No problems on the first case, I correctly receive Notifications once I click the "SEND" button on the Firebase Console. My problem is on the second point, I'm missing various information but I know that:

- I have to do a REST call to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.
- I have to use a Topic Messaging, how to do that?

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
    "to": "/topics/my_custom_topic",
    "data":
    {
        "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    }
}
```

I've used this with **Postman** but nothing to do. Is someone so kind to guide me?

Sources: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: you can send it directly from the firebase console

Comment: Can you please tell me in which way I should use the console to reach my goal?